Are there any open-source Talmud?
I would like to partially mark the tzures hadaf of mesechta Makkos, print it out for others, and put it on-line. But I do not want to worry about copyright laws. Does anyone know where I can download a mesechta and print it out or put it on-line?

https://www.shas.org/2012/08/16/jewish-texts/

@rosends you should put that as answer.

The Talmud is no younger than the Medieval period. Anything written in the medieval period is no longer covered by copyright, in any jurisdiction (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) and can legally be copied freely.
The term open source can't really be applied to a book like the Talmud. Open source implies the existence of a source code, which you can modify. There is no source code for the Talmud and in any case you are not going to produce your own version of the Talmud. What you probably mean is a free version of the Talmud. Open source is a much stronger claim than "free" - it implies freedom to modify and adapt to your own purposes (under the condition that the modified version is also open source) which doesn't really make sense for the Talmud.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The core of the question was "Does anyone know where I can download a mesechta and print it out or put it on-line?" - your answer doesn't really help with this

While your comments are true as regards the Talmudic text itself and that of the major classical commentators like Rashi and Tosafos, various modern editions incorporate new features that may well be under copyright.  For example, translations into modern Hebrew of the old French terms that Rashi sometimes uses, which presumably required labor to compile, and I would expect to enjoy copyright protection.

@YehoshuaKahan There is a version of the Talmud at https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Talmud but it's beyond crappy. If someone spent the time to do a proper job, that would be very much in the spirit of the wiki project.
